# Force Sony Music app to refresh album art from MP3 files

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia, music-player, album-art

I have a Sony M4 Aqua, running Android version 5.0.

I copied some MP3 files from my computer to the SD card in the phone. Then, some weeks later, on my computer, I updated the album art in the ID3 tag of some of the MP3s, reconnected the phone and overwrote the MP3 files on the SD card. However, the Music app on the phone (which came preinstalled and I believe is a Sony app) is still showing the old album art. Presumably the app has its own database of album art, which needs to be refreshed from the MP3 files' ID3 tags. How can I force it to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by playing a track from the album that showed the 'old' art, went into update music info and deleted the album art. All of a sudden it displayed the 'new' art. This seems to clean up the image cache for that album. Whether this clears the whole cache, I am not sure, but now all albums show updated art.

Comment: Amazingly, this works! What a hack! As you suggest, it needs to be done on an album-by-album basis.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go into Settings, Apps, Music, Storage and tap clear all data.